# change post status post after 7 days using interval

Tags: angular, rxjs

angular2 and observable learning in process, i'm wondering if we can use interval to call a function to change the status of a post after  7 days.
this is what i'm about to do.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

  Observable.interval(1000 * 60 * 1440).subscribe(x => {
    doSomethinghere();
  });
```

Comment: That's what cronjobs are for.

Comment: yes but i'm using firebase , don't know anything about a server except what i know with firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works if you ensure that the browser client stays running uninterrupted for such a long time. Also what about multiple clients running the same code? How would they know if another instance on another machine already did the update recently.

Such things should be done by the server, not by the client.

It would also be better to store the time of the last update somewhere and have a task that repeatedly (once per day or hour or minute) the passed duration since the last check and if it's => `1000 * 60 * 1440` update again. This way you don't depend on your application code to run uninterrupted.

Comment: i'm using firebase that's why i was wondering to use interval, wiil look for a minimal nodejs server for doin that, thanks